# Galaxy Note Resolution

Tags: android, resolution, galaxy

I am talking about Device resolution not screen size.

I saw many previous questions' answers that was something like 320 x480, i think this is screen size. Correct me if i am wrong.

For example, Samsung Galaxy Note Resolution is 1280 x 800 pixel.

How do i get this value in java programming?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try [this](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2009/08/exercise-get-screen-resolution-using.html) example on how to get information about the device display.

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
            int width = display.getWidth();  // deprecated
            int height = display.getHeight();  // deprecated
            Log.d("hai",width+"");
            Log.d("hai",height+"");
            DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
            getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
            double x = Math.pow(width/dm.xdpi,2);
            double y = Math.pow(height/dm.ydpi,2);
            double screenInches = Math.sqrt(x+y);
            Log.d("hai","Screen inches : " + screenInches+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

800x1280px is the resolution according to http://www.phonegg.com/compare/27/Samsung-I9100-Galaxy-S-II-vs-Samsung-Galaxy-Note.html

this question should tell you how to get the resolution. 
[Get screen dimensions in pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1016896/android-how-to-get-screen-dimensions)

Answer (score 0):

Use this simple code to get the resolution.

```
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay(); 
        int  width = display.getWidth();
        int height= display.getHeight();
        TextView w=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        w.setText(""+width);
        TextView h=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView4);
        h.setText(""+height);
```